# Facebook Disable Enhanced Auth Dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

How can i disable the Enhanced Auth Dialog?

I don`t have the Enhanced Auth Dialog Setting in my Advanced App Settings.

So, what I´ve got to do.

Thx & bye,

J

Answer (score 0):

The enhanced Auth dialog has been standard for all apps for quite a while now.

And no, you can not “disable” it (any more).

What’s your problem with it, anyway?

Comment: It`s just another window the User has to confirm and in some cases this might be superfluous. But Ok, I' ve done some research cause a colleague asked me about this and I just want to get sure that there really is no option to 'disable' this. So, there isn't one...

Comment: I don’t see where it might be _“superflous”_ – either you require the user to connect to your app and maybe require some permissions while doing it, or you don’t. And anyways, the user is already used to seeing this dialog, because every app uses it – so that’s not much of a hassle. Having a _different_ dialog for a few apps, now that I’d call a break of user expectations.

Comment: Many of different dialogues or (worst case) for each app a custom dialog, that can`t be the solution - here i totally agree. But if you only have one permission + normal User data, it would be nice to change to just one dialog,  but it doesn`t work and it`s ok this way, so, thanks for your help